# How to split a search url into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, solr

So I would like to take a string like this,

> q=Sugar Beet&qf=vegetables&range=time:[34-40]

and break it up into separate pieces that can be put into an associative array and sent to a Solr Server.

I want it to look like this

> ['q'] => ['Sugar Beets],
>   ['qf'] => ['vegetables']

After using urlencode I get

> q%3DSugar+Beet%26qf%3Dvegetables%26range%3Dtime%3A%5B34-40%5D

Now I was thinking I would make two separate arrays that would use preg_split() and take the information between the & and the = sign or the = and the & sign, but this leaves the problem of the final and first because they do not start with an & or end in an &.

After this, the plan was to take the two array and combine them with array_combine().

So, how could I do a preg_split that addresses the problem of the first and final entry of the string?  Is this way of doing it going to be too demanding on the server?  Thank you for any help.

PS:  I am using Drupal ApacheSolr to do this, which is why I need to split these up.  They need to be sent to an object that is going to build q and qf differently for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression to parse query strings. PHP already has a built-in function that does exactly this. Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
$str = 'q=Sugar Beet&qf=vegetables&range=time:[34-40]';
parse_str($str, $params);
print_r($params);
```

Produces the output:

```
Array
(
    [q] => Sugar Beet
    [qf] => vegetables
    [range] => time:[34-40]
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much this is a great help.  Now should I use urlencode on this request still?

Comment: @user3210277: Depends on what you want. If you're sending these over `GET`, then it's a good practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function/.

Answer (score 0):

also:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);
```